# Dynamic Reference in Excel Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a single file that can work multiple other files data just changing some references, and I'm trying to make those in a single dynamic reference made up using different input.
It's easier to explain my intention graphically I think...

That's how my directory is:

```
Example
|
|--- **FY21**
|   |
|   |- 01_Main File FY21.xlsx
|
|--- **FY22**
|   |
|   |- 01_Main File FY22.xlsx
|
|--- **FY23**
|   |
|   |- 01_Main File FY23.xlsx
|
|--- **FY24**
|   |
|   |- 01_Main File FY24.xlsx
|
|--- Calc.xlsx
```

**[Main File](https://i.ibb.co/Y7pH0BF/pic2.png)** (*pic.1*)
**[Calc](https://i.ibb.co/VBCZJMs/pic1.png)** (*pic.2*)

---

As you can see, each file is named in the same way (`01_Main File FY**.xlsx`), and each file as the same structure inside (*pic.1*).
**!Note!** The "days" row is set as date for ease

The file I'm working in is `Calc.xlsx` and is structured like in *pic.2*.
Those are the formulas (everything else is just text input):

```
B5  >  ''[01_Main File FY
B6  >  =RIGHT(B2;2)
B7  >  .xlsx] Main'!

C3  >  =LEFT(B3;3)

/Those one works/
E3  >  =COUNTIF(INDIRECT($B$5&$B$6&$B$7&$B$10);"4")
F3  >  =COUNTIF(INDIRECT($B$5&$B$6&$B$7&$B$10);"8")

/Those one do not work/
E4  >  =SUM(--(TOCOL(FILTER(INDIRECT($B$5&$B$6&$B$7&$B$8);RIGHT(INDIRECT($B$5&$B$6&$B$7&$B$9);3)=$C$3);3)="4"))
E5  >  =SUM(--(TOCOL(FILTER(INDIRECT($B$5&$B$6&$B$7&$B$8);TEXT(INDIRECT($B$5&$B$6&$B$7&$B$9);"mmm")=$C$3);3)="4"))
```

The problem is that the formulas that are working are the ones that have as range "Sep Data Range", that is not "dynamic" but static (I have to set up this range for every single month).
The formulas that do not work are the ones with a dynamic range that change according to `C3`, but I always have this `#CALC!` error and I don't know why...

If needed I can upload the Example directory somewhere to share with you guys.

Any help would be **very** appreciated!!

---

**P.S.** *Sorry for my bad english, it's not my mother tongue! Hope I was clear enough!*